# Wrongfully getting top of the window instead of bottom of window

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js to get resources of a Laravel API periodically and with paginate(), after getting the first 10 instances I want to get the other 10, my method looks like so:

```
scroll () {
        window.onscroll = () => {
        let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

        if (bottomOfWindow) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                axios.get('/api/groups')
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("end of window");
                    Object.assign( {}, this.groups, response.data.meta.total);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
            }, 400)
        }
    }
    }
```

The bugs are:

- I am getting the message in the console when I'm scrolling from bottom TO top and arrive at the top and not vice versa as expected.
- I can't add the other 10 resources with what I have now in the other line.

If I were to console.log response.data.meta I get the following:

```
current_page: 1
from: 1
last_page: 2
path: "http://www.bla-bla.io/api/groups"
per_page: 10
to: 10
total: 20
__proto__: Object
```

What is the problem here?!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `bottomOfWindow` to:

```
(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight
```

this should correctly detect reaching bottom of the page.

Comment: Yes, now it works, thanks. However, when I reach the bottom even once it keeps repeating and doesn't stop, which means I'm doing a lot of requests, which means after a couple of seconds I get "Too many requests" Error, do you know how can I fix that?!

Comment: You can have a Boolean to determine if it should make request. Set the bool to false initially, set it to true when reach bottom & start fetching, set it to false again when get the response and the page is longer.